# How can I access the postgres type that each field needs to be mapped to in a gorm model in go?

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

assuming I have a model

```
type MyModel struct {
  FirstField    *CustomType  `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  SecondField   string       `gorm:"type:varchar(42)"`
}

type CustomType struct {
    *big.Int
}

func (CustomType) GormDataType() string {
    return "numeric"
}
```

Is there any way to find out through the db.DB object that the postgres type should be numeric for FirstField and varchar(42) for the SecondField?

I noticed that each field in form has a DataType that gets parsed in schema/field.go ParseField. Where is that being called and is it stored in the db somewhere? I noticed that I need a schema to call ParseField myself, but the db schema seems to be nil. Am I missing something? Thanks!